# Is there a way to create 'modules' in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, modularity

I'm looking into ways to create modules (or a similar concept) where many packages/functions/procedures will live in, but I only expose a few facade APIs.

The main reason for this is that I want to restrict any direct access to any non-API methods in order to promote decoupling and modularity.

I was thinking using db schemata as the 'module' system, but AFAIK it doesn't restrict access.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a user, compile all the packages/functions/procedures with that user. Create a second user and grant access to the few packages/etc you want to make available and only allow access via that user (and not directly via the owner).

Comment: You can simply have a package spexcification that only exposes those procedures/functions that you want to expose. Other code within the package body can remain private to that package as there is no way to call it without the definition being in the specification. You can use GGRANTS/ROLES to control access to your data/modules.

Comment: In PL/SQL, Public/Private access is implemented by declaring public components in the package header. Is that what you mean? What is a 'module' here?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson the 'module' is a collection of packages. I only want some packages to actually be completely public (API) while others remain hidden (internal use by the module).

Comment: Then don't grant them to anyone. (Also look at Matthew's [whitelist / `ACCESSIBLE BY`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/plsql-white-lists-using-the-accessible-by-clause-12cr1) suggestion below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a user, compile all the packages/functions/procedures with that user. Create a second user and grant access to the few packages/etc you want to make available and only allow access via that user (and not directly via the owner).

Something like:

```
CREATE USER package_owner IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT LOCK;
REVOKE CREATE SESSION FROM package_owner;

CREATE PACKAGE package_owner.your_api
  PROCEDURE your_api_procedure;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_owner.your_api
  PROCEDURE your_api_procedure IS BEGIN NULL; END;

  PROCEDURE private_procedure IS BEGIN NULL; END;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE package_owner.your_hidden_package
  PROCEDURE your_hidden_procedure;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_owner.your_hidden_package
  PROCEDURE your_hidden_procedure IS BEGIN NULL; END;
END;
/

CREATE USER access_point IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO access_point;
GRANT EXECUTE ON package_owner.your_api TO access_point;
```

Now you can connect to the user `access_point` and execute the `your_api` package but cannot execute `your_hidden_package`.

Also note that, while `your_api` is executable from the `access_point` user, the `private_procedure` is not in the package specification so this is only visible within the same package.

Comment: This could be a potential solution, but unfortunately we already have heavy use of users in the db. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I've been looking into this more and more. I think your suggestion makes more sense in terms of effort and traceability. Funnily enough, I discovered that our lead architect wrote the chapter "PL/SQL programming in the large" in "Expert PL/SQL Practices" and explains this exact concept.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to control access, but not necessarily visibility, use the PL/SQL white list feature in Oracle 12.1.

E.g.,

#### Set up

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE public_api AS
  PROCEDURE p1_pub;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE private_api 
  ACCESSIBLE BY (PACKAGE public_api)  -- This is the key part of the feature
AS
  PROCEDURE p2_pvt;
END private_api;
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY public_api AS
  PROCEDURE p1_pub IS
  BEGIN
    private_api.p2_pvt;
  END;
END public_api;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY private_api AS
  PROCEDURE p2_pvt IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from private API!');
  END;
END private_api;
```

#### Test access via public API

```
BEGIN
  public_api.p1_pub;
END;
/
```

*Result:* Hello from private API!

#### Test direct access to private API

```
BEGIN
  private_api.p2_pvt;
END;
/
```

*Result:* PLS-00904: insufficient privilege to access object PRIVATE_API

Comment: Even though I haven't used it yet in scale, the feature seems tedious to use. I'll basically need to put assess modifiers on the whole call stack. On the other hand, we usually put a private/public modifier on every class/method so this is similar I guess. This seems the closest thing to what I'm looking for. Thanks for your time!